# Detecting click outside React component and single state for hover

Tags: reactjs

I have made a navbar, which holds a searchbar, and 3 icons.
On clicking these icons, a modal is rendered.

**I wanted help with two things.**

1. Closing the modals on outside clicks!, and
2. The hover element is slow because it has three states, every time it is called it re-renders the code from bottom to top. I wanted the hover to have **one state assigned to one parent element**. **But on doing that, the hover effect for all three buttons gets activated at the same time.**

**Code is up on** : https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-snowflake-he95w

Please feel free to edit the code and pass me the edited fork.

I have tried handleBlur, passing an event, and eventListener.

https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-snowflake-he95w

Expected - **Modal rendered on screen should get disappeared on clicking outside the modal.**

P.S - semantic UI icons are not rendering, but they are there. They will activate if you hover over them.
Credits - SVG close icon problem solved by Drew Reese.

Comment: Your codesandbox isn't running for me.

Comment: Try this: i have shifted the entire project to a new sandbox.
It should be working now : 
https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-snowflake-he95w

Comment: P.S - semantic UI icons are not rendering, but they are there. They will activate if you hover over them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I see.  Your `ToolBar` is the controlling component, i.e. the state about whether or not each toolbar item is open is stored there. You need to pass a close handler to the children components so when a "close" button is clicked it is calling the callback the parent passed in.

Here is a fork of your sandbox where I pass in an `onCloseClick` callback to the calendar/picker thing that simply toggles that state value back to false to close it.  The picker then just assigns that callback as its `onClick` handler for the contaning  for the close button.

[image: Edit floral-darkness-v3ftw]

You can apply the same logic to the other two components.

Note: since the icons aren't rendering for me either I added some text to the buttons so they are easier to find/see.